# Tensorflow: what's the SplitByWorker exactly done in distributed version?

Tags: tensorflow

In Tensorflow, there's a placement algorithm (which named as placer.cc in master branch) used for mapping node (op) to devices.

Supposed that in distributed TF, there's

- 1 client graph and 2 workers(or maybe more)
- Without specifying node operations to specified workers or devices on workers such as `with tf.device("/job:worker/task:7"):`
- Without using `tf.train.replica_device_setter()` for model replication on workers.

Question:

1. **What's the `SplitByWorker` actually done?**

   I've read the `SplitByDevice` and it seems to retrive by `node->device_name()` if user explicitly specified a device and placement algo places the whole worker0 subgraph to `/job:worker0/gpu:0`
2. **Is there any API or tf source code that actually make partition of client graph to different subgraphs, and send to different workers?**

   I know that `tf.train.replica_device_setter()` is used to create **replicas** on workers and for place parameters to `ps`. But without using this, can tensorflow partition model for me if there's more than 1 workers? (Obviously 1 worker get the whole client graph as its "subgraph")
3. **What's the default option for tensorflow if the client doesn't partition the graph all all?**

   If the ans of 2 is NO, then I must partition by myself through explicit specifying. But how would tf do to if the client doesn't partition the graph all? Like placement algorithms default option is put all nodes on `GPU:0`, would it place the whole client graph to worker0 without partition and let worker1 be idle?

Please give me some insight for this, any answers or source code references are appriciated (: